# How to check screen type programmatically in android (IPS or OLED)

Tags: android, screen

I want to add a device screen type detection feature to my app. If the screen is IPS, a dark gray theme will be offered. If the screen is AMOLED, a black theme will be applied. Some applications such as AIDA64 can detect the screen type. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to do this. It's possible to try pulling this data from some online website (like GSM Arena), or maybe there are other databases that you could use. But you definitely in Android that lets you do that